# SSRS Can not update subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

Our SSRS server was recently moved to a new server. The database was copied over and everything is working fine.

However, I can no longer update any existing subscriptions. Creating new subscriptions works fine but when I try to update a subscription which existed before the change over I get the following error:

`An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error for more details. (rsInternalError)`

When I check the logs I can not see anything for the time of the update. When I look in the subscriptions table though, the modified date is the time of the update.

I am the owner of the report and my userId is the same as the old server.

Has something been missed when the server was changed?

Do I have to recreate subscriptions manually?

Comment: Did you move `reportservertempdb`?

Comment: Yes it has been moved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by an error with the user permissions for sysadmin.

Adding “NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE” as sysadmin in the SQL server instance resolved the issues.